# Loading JSON from localhost using XMLHttpRequest keeps generating CORS error

Tags: javascript, json, cors

I'm a new student to javascript.  I have been practicing loading JSON from localhost to a local html file, but seeing CORS errors continuously.

[Issue]:  Different CORS error messages on Chrome / Firefox

- Chrome:  *"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:/// ...(local path)... charStat.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."*
- Firefox:  *"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:/// ...(local path)... charStat.json. (Reason: CORS request not http)."*

[What I've tried]

- Set up a simple web server using php + nginx.  No domain, just localhost (http://127.0.0.1)
- Locate JSON file under localhost (http://127.0.0.1/charStat.json)
- In Firefox about:config, opt-out "privacy.file_unique_origin" (set to 'false')

**battle.html (local file)**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en-US">

  <!-- abbreviated -->

  <body>
    <div id = "charNow">
      <table id= "chardata" border="2">
        <thead>
          <th>Class</th>
          <th>CT</th>
          <th>Level</th>
          <th>HP</th>
          <th>EN</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="js/battle.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  </html>
```

**battle.js (local file)**

```
// abbreviated

const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
const path = 'http://127.0.0.1/charStat.json';

const statTable = function () {
  $.getJSON(`charStat.json`, function(data) {
    $.each(data.statsByClass, function(i, f) {
      let tblRow = "<tr>"
      + "<td>" + f.class + "</td>"
      + "<td>" + f.ct + "</td>"
      + "<td>" + f.statTable[1].level + "</td>"
      + "<td>" + f.statTable[1].hp + "</td>"
      + "<td>" + f.statTable[1].en + "</td>"
      + "</tr>"
      $(tblRow).appendTo("#chardata tbody");
    });
  });
}

function loadJSONFile(file, callback) {
  request.open(`GET`, file, true);
  request.responseType = 'json'; 
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status == `200`) {
      callback(request.response);
    }
  }
  request.send(null);
}

loadJSONFile(path, statTable);
```

**charStat.json (under localhost)**

```
{
  "statsByClass" : [
  {
    "class" : "Warrior",
    "ct" : 300,
    "statTable" : [
      { "level" : 0, "hp" : 1000, "en" : 200, "str" : 20, "vit" : 16, "agl" : 10, "spd" : 15, "int" : 8, "xpToNextLv" : 1 },
      { "level" : 1, "hp" : 1200, "en" : 300, "str" : 24, "vit" : 20, "agl" : 12, "spd" : 19, "int" : 9, "xpToNextLv" : 300 },
      { "level" : 2, "hp" : 1400, "en" : 300, "str" : 26, "vit" : 22, "agl" : 13, "spd" : 19, "int" : 9, "xpToNextLv" : 400 },

  // ... abbreviated ...
    ]
  }
]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the json file (charStat.json) to the same directory where battle.html (and battle.js) is.

Start a local server ->
then you can load the json via ajax call:

```
fetch('charStat.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Thank you @Marc.  I added the `fetch` codes into my js file and it worked.  Luckily, didn't need to move charStat.json file but used the `path` that I defined and still worked.